# Right place to flush the object

Tags: java

I have written a small piece of code for printing:

```
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512);
            out.write(msg + '\n');
            out.flush();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Test failed ",
                    e);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Test failed", e);
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out = null;
            }
        }
```

Flushing of obj is done in the try block only. So is it a good way to do it or should I flush the object in the finally block?

Comment: I normally prefer, just before closing the writer/stream. I'm sure someone will pour more light on it.

Comment: Use `out.close()` instead of `out=null`

Comment: `out.close()` is missing. do you have any specific reasons?

Comment: I think by mistake he wrote `out = null` instead of `out.close()`

Comment: @Kartic I don't think it is a typo as `out.close()` should be in `try-catch` block which is also missing.

Comment: Basically , what is the purpose of out.close()?
I b'lve its assigning to null only ...M'i right ?

Comment: **No** when you `close` an output stream, It is unable to write at any future time. But assigning `null` to `out` means that the instance of the `BufferedWriter` still exists and has the capability to write garbage to the output.

Comment: Also from your previous comment I feel you are basically wanting to close the `BufferedWriter` referenced by `out` variable. If you want to close it then what is the utility of flushing it?

Answer (score 4):

Use modern syntax if you can and don't worry about all that. Closing will automatically flush it, so just use the try-with-resources syntax. This code is much shorter and more readable:

```
    try(BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512)) {
        out.write(msg + '\n');
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IOException e) {
        logger.info("Test failed due to exception.");
        throw new IllegalStateException("Test failed", e);
    }
```

See more about [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if you are unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: Is it really required to flush in try block or it can be done only in finally block ?

Comment: Closing will automatically flush. If you use try/with syntax closing will be handled for you. So unless you have a reason to manually flush, there's no need.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends."  When do you want the text to be available for reading?  If you don't need any of the text to be available for reading (i.e. no other process is actively waiting for on the stream as input), then you don't need to flush the stream until you are done with it (in the finally block).  But you don't even need to explicitly do this since closing the stream automatically flushes it.

If another process is waiting on the stream, then you should flush whenever you want that output available to the other process.  Flushing too often negates the benefits of buffering, however.

As others have noted, flushing and closing a stream can also throw an exception, so these actions should also be in their own try/catch block (a static utility method can be helpful for reducing the amount of boilerplate code when working with streams).